# Omnibox doesn't auto-hide when scrolling down on Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I don't know why, but my Chrome sometimes has an error that disables the tab grid layout flag and the auto-hide omnibox when scrolling down (I don't know the name of that flag).

So, I have enabled the tab grid layout flag, but I can't enable the auto-hide omnibox when scrolling down thing.

How can I enable it again?

Comment: Its not obvious what you  mean, a screenshot would help